# Need some advice on setting a svn repository (VSS to TortoiseSVN migration)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visual-sourcesafe

We're trying to migrate from vss to tortoise svn. I've done some research and people said that VisualSVN + TortoiseSVN was the way to go.

I'm using them and slowly i'm getting the hang of it, but i want to set the repositories with our projects that are actually on vss. Is there an easy approach? I've never done something like this before. I don't want to use migrating tools for this. Call me paranoid, but i'm afraid that it could 'break' something.

Could you guys give me some examples on populating a repository with an existing vss project?

Comment: Maybe use the same working copy on your hard drive to update to next revision of VSS (from oldest to newest), and commit to SVN. Later, if you wish, manually fix the commit users and times, and add comments. This is essentially what any migrating tool would do, but if you don't want them then do it yourself.